# Write a while loop that prints all positive numbers that are divisible by 10 and less than a given number n

Tags: java

I have this homework problem and I cannot seem to get it at all. the suggested outcome if **n** were to be **100** would be
**10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90**

I know my question is probably really stupid but I cannot seem to understand this for the life of me.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("n: ");
      int n = in.nextInt();
      
      while (n % 10 < 1)
      {
         System.out.print(n + " ");
         n = n - 1;
      }
      System.out.println();
```

Comment: The best way to start debugging is to start stepping through each iteration of the loop. If `n` is 100, what is `n % 10`?  Now let's subtract 1, now `n` is 99.  What is `n % 10` now?  Is it less than 1?  Is the while loop condition satisfied?  Maybe we need to revisit the while loop condition.  And, while you're rethinking your strategy, you might notice that you need to count up, not down.  You'll need to keep track of the counter and the limit.  That means you need two variables now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, you can do it with help of an extra variable.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("n: ");
int n = in.nextInt();
int iter = 10;
while(iter < n)
{
    System.out.print(iter + " ");
    iter += 10;
}
```

Comment: The numbers are to be displayed on a single line with a space so you do not have to use `println()`. Instead, use `print()` only...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were trying to make the program without using an extra variable, but you have to take an extra variable if you want all the numbers to be displayed in increasing order. You can try this code snippet out. It will work.

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("n: ");
  int n = in.nextInt();
  int a = 10;
  while(a <= n){
    System.out.print(a+" ");
    a += 10;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in Java, but here is my solution in C++ where I just decrement n by 10 because it needs to round down.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "n: " << endl;
   int n; 
   cin >> n;

   int count = 0;
   while (count < (n-10))
   {  
      count += 10;
      
       cout << count " ";
   }

   cout << endl;
    
   return 0;
}
```